# Classic ASP on IIS 7 Windows Server 2008 64 Bit in 32-bit mode

Tags: asp-classic, 64-bit

I need to setup an old ASP site on our Win64 box that is running II7/Win 2008.

The site runs on an MS Access database (no option to upgrade the db), so due to the MS Access 64-bit driver 'issue'. I've set the site to run in 32-bit mode via the IIS Application Pool, which should allow me to use the 32-bit MS Access drivers?

But as soon as I switch the site to 32-bit mode I get:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

I can run classic ASP code fine (without any db connections) in 64-bit mode, but 32-bit mode seems to kill the site completely.

Answer (score 1):

In IIS, go into the site and double click on ASP in the right hand pane to get the config up, now set Enable Client-side Debugging to TRUE and also Send Errors to Browser to TRUE.

[image: Settings]

Now to see exactly what the errors are then load the localhost page of the site up on the server 2008 box in IE or whatever browser, you should now see a proper error message which you can set about fixing.

### EDIT

Have a look here - http://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/archive/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7.aspx it has several scenarios of why this error occurs and several fixes for each, you may find one that will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Robbie, I'll give that a go next week when I'm back at work

Comment: I've tried the above & still get the above error. The log files contain no error details too.